# Google Sheets formula to calculate sum of values in one column which match multiple columns in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I need a formula in Sheet 2 column D which will look up the values of columns B and C in Sheet 1 column A and calculate the sum of the values in column C. So for example, D2 will return 36.

Sheet 1:
[image: sheet1]

Sheet 2
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({Sheet1!B:C}, 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. If i had a Sheet3 with a list of url's in column A and a list of the number of transactions in column B, what formula would then go in Sheet2 D2 to calculate the total transactions of the url's in B2 and C2?